# Member for in profile displays unexpected value

Tags: support, user-profile

I´ve just signed up to Programmers and i noticed in my profile that "member for" indicates that i´m a member since 3 months.

I´ve expected an other value like "less than 1 month" or "1 day".

Is this a bug or the default value for new users.

Answer (score 2):

Well, someone from an IP address in "Siegen 07 Germany" created your account back in February. (I can provide email addresses and specific IPs if necessary, but I am not sure that would be advisable in a public area.)

Are you sure you didn't just have a duplicate account you created earlier and forgot about?

Comment: I can´t remember beeing on Programmers, but "Siegen 07 Germany" indicates that i created the account. But why is my visit rate only 2 days (yesterday and today) and not lets say 3 days when i was on February on Programmers?

Answer (score 1):

Interesting, are you sure you didn't link your SO account to Programmers at any point?

Comment: Of course, also i copied the profile of my SO accout to Programmers.

Comment: @Jehof: I mean before you logged in today.

Comment: The account history shows first login today.

Comment: @Anna: In that case I have no idea. We'll need someone higher up to take a look.

Comment: Puh..I think not. Yesterday it was the first time that i was on Programmers.